# 'Could not load NIB in bundle' from iOS Static Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, xib, ios-frameworks

I am creating a static iOS framework (default template in Xcode 6) that includes xib files.

However I am having trouble loading the nib files when adding my framework to another app, I'm getting the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/89B7C8F1-698A-4E0B-AD8F-4DB414A6001B/Sample.app> (loaded)' with name 'MyNibName''
```

I have tried several solutions, some outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502279/unable-to-use-ios-framework-which-is-internally-using-xib-file). I still could not resolve the issue.

I see a lot of references to [this popular project](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework) which is now unsupported because xcode has the built in feature. Should I be using this instead?

In my framework target I have the xib files included in the 'Copy Bundle Resources' build phase and I see them inside the built framework directory, however, I noticed that the structure of the framework produced does not follow the structure outlined in [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html). Even when I changed the framework structure (using versions and linking the `Header` and `Resources` folders to the current version) I still couldn't resolve the issue.

I tried loading my nib in the following ways:

**1** loading the bundle by framework name, the bundle is `nil` in this case

```
NSString *resourceBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myframework" ofType:@"framework"];
resourcesBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:resourceBundlePath];
self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyNibName" bundle:resourcesBundle];
```

---

**2** Creating a resource bundle and adding it to the framework. Also is `nil`. Note that this solution works if I add the bundle to the project separately, but that defeats the purpose of the framework.

```
NSString *resourceBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"resources" ofType:@"bundle"];
resourcesBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:resourceBundlePath];
self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyNibName" bundle:resourcesBundle];
```

---

**3** Loading bundle by class, still did not work, however it returns the same app bundle as in `[NSBundle mainBundle]`. The `FrameworkClass` is any class embedded in the framework.

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[FrameWorkClass class]];
```

---

**4** Loading the main bundle with `[NSBundle mainBundle]` which doesnt and shouldnt work.

---

I think what is happening is that the resources of the framework are not being included in the final app.

What am I missing? has anyone been able to use the default static framework template in xcode to make a framework with nib files?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using for loading the nib ?

Comment: You can use : `NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[YourFrameWorkClass class]];`

Comment: Is bundle prints nil now ? Also check your framework and check the bundle and nib is there or not.

Comment: @MidhunMP no its not nil in this case, its the app bundle. This is what I get when I log it: `</private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/01AD75AF-125D-4B40-9757-B901AB6ECDC0/Sample.app> `

Comment: yes the nib is in the bundle, just checked

Comment: @KDaker Have you found solution?

Comment: @krotov I have not. I ended up not using nibs, setting up with just view controllers. I'll look at it again when I have time

Comment: @KDaker NSBundle * bundle = `[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.something.FrameworkName"];` worked for me

Comment: @krotov I remember that did not work for me when I tried it. I will have to look into it again though. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @KDaker: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @KushalAshok sorry for the late response just noticed this. I did not find a solution at the time.

Comment: Just in case if any one still having problem

     NSBundle* resourcesBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:resourcesBundle];
    if (self) {
}
    return self;
}

Answer (score 27):

This should load your bundle.

**Swift**

```
let frameworkBundleID  = "com.framework.bundleId";
let bundle = Bundle(identifier: frameworkBundleID)
```

**Objective C**

```
NSString* const frameworkBundleID  = @"com.framework.bundleId";
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:frameworkBundleID];
```

Comment: perfect and precise answer , liked it great job

Comment: This worked for me, but does not fix the problem if a 3rdparty framework (static library) that you embed in your library is searching for `nib` resources supposed to be in the root folder of their part...

Answer (score 4):

this work for me:

import loginFramework/ClassA.h

```
NSBundle* resourcesBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[ClassA class]];
ClassA * class = [[ClassA alloc]initWithNibName:@"ClassA" bundle:resourcesBundle];
UINavigationController * navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:class];

[self.window setRootViewController:navigation];
```

in app delegate in this case, and in the header of Framework add
 #import "ClassA.h"

if you want, I can send you an example

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT v5**

I have created a variable in constant file

```
var frameworkBundle:Bundle? {
    let bundleId = "com.framework.bundleId"
    return Bundle(identifier: bundleId)
}
```

Then whenever I need bundle value I directly pass it like

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCVCell", bundle: frameworkBundle), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCVCell")
```